# Facebook: Graph API java library

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Who knows a good Java library for using Facebook's graph API?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a list of good Facebook API in Java  [facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html).
The simplest one is [restFB](http://restfb.com/). On their page, there's sample code that shows you how to use restFB.

Comment: I tried out restFB and liked it very much. The only downside is that (as of today) it isn't in the maven repository.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of RestFB.  It's now Mavenized :)

Comment: I think `Facebook4J` and `restFB` are two different libraries. Anyhow, I use `Facebook4J` and it works great. Tried authentication (code+token) and search. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend restFB.  It is simple and easy to use, the sample code is very clear and can quickly hands on it. Please check its web site: http://restfb.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try out BatchFB, it's designed to get your data back with the minimum number of calls to Facebook:

http://code.google.com/p/batchfb/

Answer (score 2):

Also http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html
But not tested it yet by myslef.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a something more like Java EE solution, you can check out spring:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/